# Python - Re-Order CSV columns to match DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, apache-spark

Assume I have a table/dataframe with the following columns:

[image]

Now, I have a csv file that has values that can be added to this table, but not in the right order:

[image]

Is there a way to order the columns in the csv to match the format of the Table/Dataframe? (Assume this applies for many columns/rows of data.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both dataframes have the same columns, you can just read the csv file and try this:

```
df2 = df2[df1.columns]
```

Or:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
```